# Pandas np.where or np.select generate multiple columns in 1 line code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df:

```
contract    RB  BeginDate   ValIssueDate    EndDate Valindex0
1   A00118  46  19000100    19880901    19841231    50
2   A00118  46  19850100    19880901    99999999    50
3   A00118  47  19000100    19880901    19831231    47
4   A00118  47  19840100    19880901    19841299    47
```

I need to add new columns based on conditions:

```
condition = True

df['Valindex0']=np.where(condtion,df['Valindex0'],None)
df['RB']=np.where(condtion,df['RB'],None)
```

is there anyway I can do it by 1 line like this:

```
conditions=[True,True]

df[['Valindex0','RB']]=np.select[conditions,[df['Valindex0'],df['RB']],default=None]
```

or

```
df['Valindex0'],df['RB']=np.select[conditions,[df['Valindex0'],df['RB']],default=None]
```

Comment: `df.loc[condition, 'RB'] = None`?

Answer (score 0):

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will work if all of the arguments are compatible shapes. One option would be to [`tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) the condition to be the same shape as the columns of interest:

```
condition = df['RB'].eq(46)  # Some more interesting condition than True
df[['RB', 'Valindex0']] = np.where(
    np.tile(condition.values[:, None], 2), # Make condition match DataFrame columns
    df[['RB', 'Valindex0']],
    None
)
```

`df`:

```
  contract    RB  BeginDate  ValIssueDate   EndDate Valindex0
0   A00118    46   19000100      19880901  19841231        50
1   A00118    46   19850100      19880901  99999999        50
2   A00118  None   19000100      19880901  19831231      None
3   A00118  None   19840100      19880901  19841299      None
```

Multiple conditions can be done as well by creating a structure that is of the correct shape (like another DataFrame):

```
df[['RB', 'Valindex0']] = np.where(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'cond1': df['RB'].eq(46),
        'cond2': df['Valindex0'].eq(47)
    }),
    df[['RB', 'Valindex0']],
    None
)
```

`df`:

```
  contract    RB  BeginDate  ValIssueDate   EndDate Valindex0
0   A00118    46   19000100      19880901  19841231      None
1   A00118    46   19850100      19880901  99999999      None
2   A00118  None   19000100      19880901  19831231        47
3   A00118  None   19840100      19880901  19841299        47
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'contract': ['A00118', 'A00118', 'A00118', 'A00118'],
    'RB': [46, 46, 47, 47],
    'BeginDate': [19000100, 19850100, 19000100, 19840100],
    'ValIssueDate': [19880901, 19880901, 19880901, 19880901],
    'EndDate': [19841231, 99999999, 19831231, 19841299],
    'Valindex0': [50, 50, 47, 47]
})
```